# When copying information into another layers attribute table objects turn invisible

Tags: table, copy

When I try to copy the information of one layer into another via attribute tables the data is shown in the table but it's not visible (when I push the button in the attribute table to show only visible objects the new copied ones are not shown anymore). What is my mistake? How can I make the "new" objects visible?

First I built a .shp layer and into this one I want to load all my .gpx data. I I already did this (2 years ago), but now it won't work anymore and I don't know where my mistake is. The only difference I could find is that now by saving the first layer as ESRI shapefile is that I now get 6 instead of 5 files earlier on. Now there is also a .cpg file

I'm not able to explain anymore detailed in ways of informatics.

Comment: Which software are you working with? Please be a bit more detailed on your workflow.

Comment: I work with QGIS 3.6.2. I´ve layers in the right formation. I duplicate one of those and save: Layer -> Save as:ESRI-Shapefile-enter name and folder where all other layers of this project are saved-use project-KBS-change or click nothing else-say ok. Old data is shown on layer. when I then open my gpx data via GPS-tool and copy this data onto the duplicated and newly saved layer it exists in the attribute table but is not shown as dots on the card. When I mark (in attribute table) show only visible data the new ones are not shown anymore. so I seem to make them invisible during the copying